# HTTP/2 400 returned for URL when using symfoy HTTP Client to make post request

Tags: symfony, firebase-cloud-messaging, payload, symfony-http-client

I want to transform a http post request tested with post man to symfony action :

[image: payload]

I want to transform the payload to a json array in symfony to send data to url :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

    class PushNotificationController extends AbstractController
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/api/push_notification", name="push_notification")
         */
        public function index()
        {
            $httpClient = HttpClient::create();
            $response = $httpClient->request('POST', 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', [
                'headers' => [
                    // 'Accept' => 'application/json',
                    // "Content-Type" => "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer token'
                ],
                'json' => [
                    'notification' => [
                        'title' => 'Portugal vs. Denmark',
                        'message' => 'My Notification Message',
                        'body' => '5 to 1',
                    ],
                    'token' => 'token'
                ],
            ]);
    
            $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
            // $statusCode = 200
            $contentType = $response->getHeaders()['content-type'][0];
            // $contentType = 'application/json'
            $content = $response->getContent();
            // $content = '{"id":521583, "name":"symfony-docs", ...}'
            $content = $response->toArray();
            // $content = ['id' => 521583, 'name' => 'symfony-docs', ...]
    
            return $content;
        }
    }
```

I got this error :

I think it's an error about the payload . any suggestions please ?

[image: error]

Comment: im sure that you have an invalid json in your request , however you can use a bundle for FCM without doing all the request by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Error 400](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream)  Invalid Json input:

> Only applies for JSON requests. Indicates that the request could not
> be parsed as JSON, or it contained invalid fields (for instance,
> passing a string where a number was expected). The exact failure
> reason is described in the response and the problem should be
> addressed before the request can be retried.

so i guess you need to review your json that you sent.
also , you can use some of the FCM Bundle from Knp or git.

Comment: thanks, i use symfony bundle to handle sending notifications